# Setting A Main Page for All "Options -Indexes" Occurances

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've already set an `Options -Indexes` in my **.htaccess** file and most of my directories now have this blank index file. Is there any efficient way that I can redirect it to my 404 page? Or possibly setting a main page for it every time a user access it?

Answer (score 1):

`Options -Indexes` cause 403 to be returned to your client.

Then you can have custom page for handling 403:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /forbidden.html
```

Populate `/forbidden.html` with your custom text to be shown in client's browsers.